# Django REST API in XML & JSON

Tags: json, django, xml, django-rest-framework

*How could I produce Django REST API in XML & JSON at the same time from a same model?*

I have a model and need to create 2 different outputs from that model, one in XML and one in JSON.

Comment: That should be pretty straight forward by specifying `DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES` in `settings.py` to the appropriate values. What do you exactly mean by **same time**? Do you want XML and JSON output generally for the whole of your REST API (all models), or just for one single particular model?

Comment: I have few models , but i want to create two type of api from only one model, and for other model JSON type is enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a custom behavior for just a particular model, you can specify the `renderer_classes` only in the view for that model.

Assuming you have a model, let's call it `Foo`:

```
# models.py
class Foo(models.Model):
    # properties
```

you can do this in your `views.py`:

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework_xml.renderers import XMLRenderer
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class FooView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, XMLRenderer)
    # the rest
```

The `XMLRenderer` is not anymore integral part of the Django REST Framework and has to be installed as an additional package:

```
$ pip install djangorestframework-xml
```

The offical documentation describes the use of [`renderers`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/).

Comment: how to accomplish this in generic views ??

Comment: Generic views extend the `APIView`, so there is no difference.